# Design database for a real estate php app, tables have too many columns

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I'm designing mysql database for a php app, which has two sections: adding advertisement for properties like house shops.. , and searching for them.

I have tables for `users, addresses, ads...`

The problem is `properties` table. I don't know if I should split that up into multiple table or should I have one big table? Columns are too many. I have up to 100 fields, like:

Property type: `house, shop, fields...` Each property type has some fields like bedrooms number for house, and other fields like air conditioning system, facilities, equipments..
What should I do? Should I divide this table into smaller tables?

Comment: I think the good design in your case, is to use a `bridge` table countrywoman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a `bridge` table. You can see on this [Link](http://www.askjohnobiee.com/2013/08/how-to-bridge-tables-and-many-to-many.html) what the bridge tables are.

Generally, you have 2 choises which are both schema-design:

1. Using just one table (named `property`) and add bulk data to it. In this case, fields are your features (like air_conditioning, bedroom numbers and so on). By defining these field as boolean and denoting 1 for "The property has this feature" and 0 for "The property has NOT this feature", You can do what you want.
2. Using a simple `bridge` table which is a table that connects the `property` table to the `features` which you should define for property items.

Actually the second approach is an applicable approach in database design. Because it is scalable i.e. You can add every new feature every time!

Hope this explanation would help you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a `properties` table, a `features` table, and a `property_features` table.

Your `properties` table would have the main information - address, listing owner, etc.

Your `features` table would be a table in which each row is a possible feature - `air_conditioning`, `rooms`, `bathrooms`, `gold_plated_toilets`, etc.

Your `property_features` table would be a list of `property_id`, `feature_id`, and an optional `value` field (which could be `true`/`false` values for `air_conditioning`, or in something like `rooms` it might be a numeric count).